# sending emails automatically using php

Tags: php, mysql, email

Sorry if this was too easy one.

I am struck with a problem for 3 days.
I need to send emails to the persons  whose licence is going to expire.
The expiry dates will be in mysql database..
I am searching for it since three days,but every answer described is to "start a task manager".
But i don't understand how the task started in our system can be performed in server..?
Is there a way to send emails automatically without manual interaction.
I found lot on CRON JOB.But how can i install it in the server.

Please help me if anyone has faced this earlier.
Thanks in advance

Comment: it is there with my MD.can we make it in cpanel

Comment: tell me about your operative system...

Comment: Idk what you are talking about, but if you have cpanel is too easy...

Comment: you can set a cron in cpanel see http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/CpanelDocs/CronJobs

Comment: my operating system is windows7

Comment: @Phani If your site is hosted on Windows 7, use Windows Task Scheduler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok if you have the php to send emails when the licence is going to expire, as you said you have to use CRON JOBs, if you have cPanel in your webhosting you have them installed.

http://gyazo.com/20d34f0daa306ab17ac6eb3ce3cce561.png

http://gyazo.com/8805ff782cfa906f376bcc6a118dd016.png

On the last image, you will se a command line.

There you should type:

GET http://yourdomain.com/yourphpfile.php

Where it says "hour" click the select and click "every hour" then add the new cron and your php file will be called every hour.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a Linux host, you can use a [cron job](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) to check for expired licences. If you're on a Windows host, you can use [Windows Task Scheduler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler). If you don't have access to either, there are external services such as [Monitor.us](http://www.monitor.us/en/website-monitoring), which will visit your web page every hour or so.